# shell script vs. perl for an install script - how ubiquitous is perl?

Tags: perl, shell

I am wanting to create an install script in the fashion of npm's (`curl http://example.com/install.sh | sh`) but it leaves me asking the question: can I just write the script in perl?  As far as I know, perl is installed by default on at least ubuntu, RHEL & OS X - so I'm wondering in the year 2011, can I not write shell and still be generic enough for everyone? Is there a third and better option?

This would be targeting a user's development box, not staging or production.

What I want to do specifically is use this install script to bootstrap a development environment easily without the overhead of creating and maintaining packages.  The script would have 4 steps:

1. check and make sure git is installed
2. use git to clone a repo to cwd
3. pull down and save a perl control script to /usr/bin, make it executable
4. add some environment variables (related post: [linux cross-distro environment variable modification via script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656327/linux-cross-distro-environment-variable-modification-via-script))

That's it.  My thinking is this is simple and generic enough to use a bootstrap script rather than a package. And my target audience is a user's unix or linux local development system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to simply use the existing, well-oiled and -used (development) toolchain for the language the target app is written in. Not doing so frivolously discards the network effects gained from the ecologies that have grown around them.

- C: GNU autotools
- Haskell: Cabal
- Perl: [EU::MM](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker), [M::B](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild), [M::I](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aInstall)

etc. etc.

Installing from the Web should be reserved for conveniently **bootstrapping** a user's system into the development environment.

Do tell more details about your software to get less general advice.

---

Edit: response to your addendum.

I dissuade you from a Web installer. This isn't bootstrapping an installation tool, this is plain installation of software and it should be done with with e.g. a Module::Build subclass.

Answer (score 3):

I think perl is ubiquitous enough for you to write your installer in it. Shell is a lot more awkward anyway.

You might want to consider actually packaging your application as a deb or rpm or even using [makeself](http://www.megastep.org/makeself/) rather than providing a raw script.

Comment: And/Or as the case may be. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of the various distributions of perl:

https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/distributions

Even if perl doesn't ship on every little obscure distro it's just an apt-get (or whatever) away.  You might run into problems due to the various versions of perl installed however.

Comment: I just want to clarify that I didn't mean that you shouldn't use perl, just don't get too fancy!

Answer (score -1):

Use something like:

```
perl -E "$( wget -q -O - http://host/intall.pl )"
```

Also you can use

```
`cmd`
```

instead of

```
$(cmd)
```

but anyway, double-quote your choice.

Comment: And gain things like a portable lstat and not GNU Vs POSIX Vs BSD Vs etc... see all core functions and modules in [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org). Note that the .pl extension is unneeded and just here for add context. Be sure that the httpd serves it as static or as text/plain.