# linux cross-distro environment variable modification via script?

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables

What is the best way to modify or create environment variables from a script in a way that is cross distro/*nix friendly?  I simply want to add a couple of environment variables via a bootstrap script, but there are so many places to do this and, for example, ubuntu prefers /etc/environment but I don't want to write a lot of logic to deal with different distros and I would like to support OS X.  Is there a best-practices way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Mac OS X bit, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) appears to have discussed it to good depth.  And, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) appears to have a decent discussion for global environment variables on Linux.

I see a /etc/environment but it is empty, on Debian system.  I think global initialization files are defined per shell, if a shell has such a file.